# use proc info to increase pc's speed

Tags: linux, performance, proc

Just to filter the answers, I am a completely beginner trying to understand the basics about Linux Filesystem. According to many resources the `proc` directory in the filesystem shows information about processes.

Is it possible to use any information therein to make the computer run faster?

Is it possible? Any interesting thing to learn and to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner, there is no need to worry about it(for a while). I find it useful to look at ( extract specific info from /proc) but at the moment you can probably use tools like top, netstat, iostat. They all process information from /proc for you and give you what is useful...

I'm not trying to sound patronizing, it may just be too overwhelming at the moment